# How to get grub menu from windows 10

Tags: windows, kali-linux, grub

I had installed Kali Linux on my system. Then I decided to make dual boot with windows 10. After successfully installing win 10, I cannot access the grub menu and system directly loads into win 10.

I tried `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi` but it didn't worked. I also tried replacing `Ubuntu` with `Kali-Linux` but things remained same

Answer (score 1):

Use the same Kali installation disc you used, and enter into rescue mode, then open a shell on your root partition for your Kali, execute this:

```
bash(To set the shell environment to bash)
grub-install <partition name>
update-initramfs -vu
```

And then reboot, change your hard drive properties in the BIOS to the hard drive that we just installed grub on.

Should boot into Grub.

Comment: what does the partition name looks like? For example!!

Comment: A partition should look like this E.g /dev/sda1. You can see all the partitions using the command **lsblk**